# Project with multiple source maps cannot find it's original TS-source-map

Tags: typescript, webpack

My App looks something like this

```
src/app.ts
/node_modules/mymodule/lib/settings.js
/node_modules/mymodule/src/settings.ts
```

app.ts - Vue Main App with eval source map
settings.js was transpiled via Bable / webpack and has it's own inline source map

In the Main-App I import settings like 
`import { settings } from '@mymodule/settings'

Now if I bundle the main app if generates a source-map for the app. But instead of referencing to the original settings.ts sources it references to the transpiled settings.js file.

Is there a way around this problem?